# python ASCII art - british flag

Tags: python, function, printing, range

I need to use ranges and functions to print the United Kingdom's flag. I have determined that I need three seperate ranges to print with. range(5) for the top two triangles, single slash, and the first three virticle lines of the red cross at the top. I figured that the repeate() function would be used for the second half of the flag, or I would just inverse the justifications for the first half.

The horizontal line going from left to right is a simple 47 lines of letters and the bottom range will be the same as the top, only flipped.

My code for the range is simply a 
red, white and blue are functions in and of themselves.

```
for t in range(5):
    print(red(1, "R") + white(3, " ") + blue(8, "B") + white(2, " ") 
+ red(2, "R") + red(3, "R") + white(2, " ") + blue(8, "B") + 
white(2, " ") + red(1, "R"))
```

My prolem is that I need to know how to off set each of the printed lines with the range, using one print statement so that I take

```
R   BBBBBBBB  BBBBBBBB  R
R   BBBBBBBB  BBBBBBBB  R
R   BBBBBBBB  BBBBBBBB  R
R   BBBBBBBB  BBBBBBBB  R
R   BBBBBBBB  BBBBBBBB  R
```

and turn it into something like this

```
R     BBBBBB  RRRRR  BBBBBB  R
 RR    BBBBB  RRRRR  BBBBB  RR
   RR   BBBB  RRRRR  BBB   RR
     RR   BB  RRRRR  BB   RR
       RR  B  RRRRR  B  RR
```

Please keep in mind that this must be printed in the terminal, thus why I use letters to repersent the colors which should br printed. I do not have the above images to the size ratio I need, but that is a simple matter of math that I can do on my own. (totaling 47 characters across and 15 down)

Comment: Formatting issues aside, my question remains the same. How does one print multiple lines from a single range, shapped differently each time it prints?


Why does your site make formatting so difficult? The way the code is appearing is how I typed it in, if there is some special characters that must be typed first, then that should be more clearly explained in some kind of instruction manual.

Comment: You got the downvotes because your question sounds a lot like a homework and you expect others to do it for you. Homework questions are OK on this site, but you need to show people an effort in solving them, only then you can expect help.

Comment: I stated that the only problem that I have is that I don't know how to alter the print statement. Everything else was done. There seems to be no information about altering lines of a print statement in a range greater than 1.

Comment: This project was completed, all one needs to do is create variables such as a = a + 1 within the range loop and you have the ability to alter the range print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

After clarification of the question I completely rewrote it.

What you are going to have to do is create a class or program it completely by hand. A start for the class would be:

```
class FlagDrawer(object):

    def __init__(lines, colors,....):
        lines = self.lines
        colors = self.colors
        other variables

    def make_lines(self.lines):
        for lines in range(self.lines):

    .
    .
    .
```

If you are just using this flag for one specific task, and only using one flag I would just suggest writing it by hand an inclosing it in triple quotes i.e.(''' text '''). There are some written about keeping the same text for pictures for making tables and use the same idea for your flag.

Comment: Thank you for posting a answer. I think there might have been some mistake in explaination as to what my red, blue and white functions are. As my colored functions are what you just explained. They allow me to input the interger and a string. Thus when I call red(2, "R") I get RR. So when I call print(red(5, "#") + blue(6, "@")), I print out #####@@@@@@ My problem is with shaping the range(5) print to make five lines which are shapped based upon what I put into the print statement.

Comment: What you are going to have to do is use a class that does specific things for a line. (this is assuming you want to do the same thing for multiple lines or colors) or just program it by hand.

Comment: Can you recommend any post or books which teach someone how to program a class?

Comment: Here [link](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) has a good tutorial of python and classes, [link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/), and Beginning Python From Novice to Professional are my personal favorites.